# Create a Y/N flag column based of Overlapping date & time

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, case, oracle12c

I'm trying to create an overlap column that indicates if there has been any overlap of time on a specific day. The example is for one individual who has worked on several tasks/jobs throughout the day. I'm struggling to get the OVERLAP_FLAG column to populate correctly. I'm working on a 12C Oracle Database & I've tried LEAD,LAG & Partition with no success. In the example all the rows should be should have a calculated OVERLAP_FLAG of 'Y'

[image]

```
CREATE "TEST1" (
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
    "JOB" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
    "START_TIME" DATE, 
    "STOP_TIME" DATE, 
    "OVERLAP_FLAG" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE)
);  

Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','A02',to_date('18-AUG-2020 09.22.31','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.59.12','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'Y');
Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','A01',to_date('18-AUG-2020 09.22.35','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.58.55','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'Y');
Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','B01',to_date('18-AUG-2020 09.22.43','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.58.32','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'Y');
Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','B02',to_date('18-AUG-2020 09.22.49','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.58.45','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'Y');
Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','C02',to_date('18-AUG-2020 09.22.56','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.58.20','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'Y');
Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','C01',to_date('18-AUG-2020 09.23.04','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.58.08','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'Y');
Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','X01',to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.57.02','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.57.03','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'Y');
Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','Y01',to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.57.11','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.57.12','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'Y');
Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','Z01',to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.57.30','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.57.31','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'Y');
Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','W01',to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.57.47','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 15.57.48','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

One option uses `exists` and a `case` expression:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when exists (
        select 1
        from test1 t1
        where 
            t1.name = t.name
            and t1.job <> t.job
            and t1.start_time < t.stop_time
            and t1.stop_time  > t.start_time
    ) then 'Y' else 'N' end overlap_flag
from test1 t
```

The predicates of the subquery describe a record with the same `name`, a different `job`, and an overlapping date range.

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c62fc8cd571c1d0743e97d7b36c3621f)**

Comment: I'm not sure this works correctly as if you add in another row that does not overlap you should get a 'N'

Insert into TEST1 (NAME,JOB,START_TIME,STOP_TIME,OVERLAP_FLAG) values ('JOE ','W01',to_date('18-AUG-2020 16.00.00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),to_date('18-AUG-2020 16.10.10','DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS'),'N');

Comment: @LeeMurray: this additional row does gets a N flag, as you [see in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e11b7a0c6a2ddba586c7b459c890d57)